# control heap size for multiple Java programs running on a single computer?

Tags: memory, java

We have 4 Java programs running on a single EC2. Due to JVM ergonomics, each one defaults to a max heap of 25% of the memory on the machine which leads to high memory usage.  I don't want to use -Xmx to set the max heap as the systemd scripts that launch these programs are used for both our development and prod EC2s which have very different amounts of memory.

I'm leaning towards using -XX:MaxRAMPercentage so that the heap will be scaled by the size of the EC2 and I can give 10% to the smaller programs and 50% to the busy program.  But most of the documentation I've seen recommends controlling heap size explicitly.  Suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! I don't fully understand what the question is. Thanks for including your research so far ("But most of the documentation I've seen recommends controlling heap size explicitly"), could you please include *why* they recommend to control the heap size directly? Are you running into any issues with `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage`? Or is your question about why a source would recommend `Xmx` over `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage`?

Answer (score 0):

In your script which launches these java process get the total installed memory on your
machine and multiply it with factors which you want to give to that particular process. For example on a 16GB machine for the process to which you want to give 50% RAM.

allocRam = 16 * 0.5 = 8

Use this value in the -Xmx${allocRam} parameter of your java process. This should work on both development and prod envs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).